# selenium webdriver link and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium with chromedriver. I am able toget the  link

by

```
lnk=browser.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload")
```

and download the file using `lnk.click()`

but instead of saving it to local folder
In the webpage link appears as

```
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><i class="fa fa-download iconfont"></i></a>
```

I don't know the name of the file, I know it is CSV File.
so I would like to open Pandas Dataframe directly.

Comment: and what you wanna do once you have a DF ? can we have sample input file as well  ?

Comment: The data is about insider trading. I will be uploading to data to mysql analyse automatically which company increased its stakes